# Can we say “If an API is following 6 constraints of REST then it’s a RESTful API”?

Tags: node.js, json, api, rest, http

Can we say “If an API is following 6 constraints of REST then it’s a RESTful API”? 
or my statement is completely wrong?

Comment: In theory yes, in practice, however, as some [use cases pointed out](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/46310.pdf) further constraints might be necessary on top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are half right.
Yes, there are 6 constraints that Mr. Roy Fielding described in his phD publication.
But, the last one "Code On Demand" is **optional**

Ref: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Can we say “If an API is following 6 constraints of REST then it’s a RESTful API”? or my statement is completely wrong?

You probably need to be detailed about the nature of the "uniform interface" constraint:

> REST is defined by four interface constraints: identification of resources; manipulation of resources through representations; self-descriptive messages; and, hypermedia as the engine of application state.

See also [REST APIs Must be Hypertext Driven](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) (Fielding 2008).

Answer (score 0):

REST defines 6 architectural constraints which make any web service – a true RESTful API.

1. Uniform interface
2. Client-server
3. Stateless
4. Cacheable
5. Layered system
6. Code on demand (***optional***)

All the above constraints help you build a truly RESTful API, and you should follow them. Still, at times, If you find yourself violating one or two constraints. Do not worry; you are still making a RESTful API – but not “truly RESTful.”